# React structure problem with same component in multiple parent component

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with my react web app.
I have Multiple components : Home, Login, Header, Footer

I do a GET request in Header to retrieve categories from API and list it in the Header menu.

The problem is when i click on link (to go in Login or Home page), the request in Header is sent again because Header component is include in Home and in Login component.

Someone have a solution for that ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please add a code snippet with your Login and Home page to help debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out using a router, such as [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/), to handle multiple pages without reloading layout stuff like your Header.

alternatively, you might want some caching to not hit the API every time your component renders

Comment: Thanks, i just need to insert my component Header in the <Router> part and not directly in Home and Login component :)